# Echoing a mySQL count with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I excecute this in phpMyAdmin and works perfectly...

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as sectionCount FROM my_table where section='0'"
```

But when I try to use it in my php file doesn't works...

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as sectionCount FROM my_table where section='0'"
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo $result;
```

Where is the error?!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($result)`. Look at what it returns you.

Comment: You need to call `$result->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Have you bothered to read any mysqli documentation that shows how to get the results of a query?

Comment: Do other Query work? Do you find any errors in log file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've read the documentation for counts and lot of questions about this in this forum too, here the solution, thanks to Barman... I had already tried with fetch_assoc() but didnt work, the solution was near...

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM my_table where section='0'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$countNumber = $row->count;
echo $countNumber;
```

Thanks to all!